# Inverting colors under OSX Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion

In previous versions of OSX, you could invert the colors on the display by hitting <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd>. It appears that they have removed that functionality in Mountain Lion.  Does anyone know how to get that functionality back?

Comment: Belongs to [apple.stackexchange.com](http://apple.stackexchange.com)?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The keyboard shortcut for that function is for some reason disabled by default in Mountain Lion, but you can enable it in

[**System Preferences>Keyboard>Keyboard shortcuts>Accessibility**](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4142983?start=0&tstart=0)

[image: Screenshot of the Setting]

Comment: it's because people go into the Apple store and ctrl-alt-cmd-8 all the screens

Comment: @CodeRarity Ah, that would make sense, although one would think that disabling accessibility functions by default instead of having a custom installer for the Apple stores would be bad for visually impaired people.

Answer (score 1):

It is still possible to do so, but I don't know the shortcut. Go to Settings > Accessibility > Display > Invert colors.

Answer (score 1):

Under the keyboard, there is a accessibility menu where you can reenable it.